# Undefined global variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, global-variables

I want to use a global variable in a CodeIgniter Controller, I tried to use the solution from this post [Codeigniter global variable within controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151990/codeigniter-global-variable-within-controller) but it doesn't work for me. I think because first I call the `session` function, and after the user's authentication the `user` function, but the web page has been refreshed and the value is lost. Is there any to store the variable somewhere after the first's function call and retrieve it later from the second function?

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

  class Auth extends CI_Controller
{
    //Constructor
      function __construct() {
          parent::__construct();
      }

    public $user;

    public function session()
    {

        require 'facebook/facebook.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(  
    'appId'  => '***********',  
    'secret' => '*****************',  
    'cookie' => true
    ));  

    $user = $facebook->getUser();

      if ($user) {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();

      } else {
        // proceed knowing you require user login and/or authentication
        $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();  
          header("Location: ".$login_url);  
      }
    }

    public function user()
    {
        echo ($user);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the link , I think it work for you
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/155141/

Answer (score 0):

You Can Define Global Constant in constant.php file under the config folder and you can acsees it any where by using that constant

Like

define('MY_VAR','MY_value');

and Now If u want to use it just do LIKE echo MY_VAR;

Comment: The problem is that I don't want Constant, its a userID and its different for every user

Answer (score 0):

PHP will allocate variables once it is defined when you call the function **user()** directly the variable doesn't exists because it is not defined.Also in order for referencing global variables you should use **$this->user**.In this scenario the variable **$user** should be a session variable.